# Apache 2.2 logging Redirects

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, mod-alias

How do I get Apache to log particular `Redirect`s in a separate log file?

I have a web site which includes links to an external site. I have been asked to keep track of how often users use these links. I can change them all to point to a redirector on my site, and use Apache `RedirectMatch` to then direct them to the correct location, but it would be easier if I could have these particular redirects logged to a separate file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define separate log file used if there is environment variable:

```
#Set your own file path and log file format
CustomLog /var/log/apache/redirects.log common env=redirected
```

Set this variable near every redirect (RedirectMatch or mod_rewrite, etc.):

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/site" redirected=1
RedirectMatch ^/site/(.*)$ http://target.example.com/$1
```

You can also use SetEnv or mod_rewrite to set environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have a separate VirtualHost with its own access_log file - e.g. if your domain is www.example.com, you set up a separate VirtualHost with the DNS name redirect.example.com, and all your links to external sites go through that host, and are recorded in that host's separate log file.